# Stop iframe from flashing white when changing its source via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an iframe:

```
<iframe id="main_frame" src="first_url.html" style="visibility:hidden;" onload="this.style.visibility = 'visible';"></iframe>
```

As you can see it has been set to not be visible while loading. This ensures that no 'white flash' occurs while the frame loads. However, if I change the source of the iframe by clicking this button:

```
<button onclick="change_view('new_url.html')">change view</button>
```

..where the javascript function to change the source is:

```
 function change_view(url) {
          var site = url
          document.getElementById('main_frame').src = site
            }
```

then I get the white flash while the source changes.  Is there is a way to change the source of the iframe without getting this white flash?

Comment: You're using `visibility:hidden`, but did you also try adding `display:none`?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. But "display: none" moves things on the page since divs will shift when that property is altered.

Comment: Does it fix the issue though? If it does, then you can just add a `<div>` wrapper around the iframe that preserves the width/height.

Comment: You could add the `visibility:hidden` after clicking button and then use `onload` event to remove it

Comment: @Hybrid I tried your div wrapper idea. It holds the position as you said but it still flashes when clicking the button :(

Comment: @m_pro_m I tried that but it still flashes.

Comment: Ah yes...the combination of both your answers worked. Thank you! I used both visibility and display properties in the iframe, locked in the div dimensions with a wrapper, and used javascript to also control visibility and display at the beginning and end of the function call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this

```
<iframe style="visibility:hidden;" onload="this.style.visibility = 'visible';" src="../examples/inlineframes1.html" > </iframe>
```

It hides iframe until fully loaded.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/get-rid-of-white-flash-when-iframe-loads/